# First up: What to call this site

Tags: discussion

This site is currently titled  "Signal Processing" with a URL of "dsp.stackexchange.com".

You are the domain experts. Does that ^^^ sound reasonable?

The name and URL was chosen because they seemed to be the most "industry-acceptable" terms that potential members would recognize at a glance.

I prefer clarity and conciseness over excessive precision when it comes to naming. Crowd-sourced names have a tendency to become overly pedantic as each group adds their own little bit. but we don't want to ACTIVELY turn away our core group, either.

**We're looking for *brevity* and "industry appropriateness" to let people know the *intent* of this site… at a glance.**

Please let us know if a change is needed; one that will be *substantively* better than what we have now.

Comment: dsp = `Digital signal proccessing`?

Comment: So it seems like dsp is very much not liked based off of the amount of up-votes and comments below. How do we get this changed? I figured it would have been done before public beta started.

Answer (score 16):

I was actually in the middle of writing a meta question.

*Signal Processing* is a good name as far as I am concerned; however, dsp.stackexchange.com is not so great. Here is why:

In [this question](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2147/is-this-proposal-intended-to-be-just-for-digital-or-is-it-for-analog-as-well) I asked if this site was *only* for digital or if it was for both. Pretty much universally everyone said it was for both. By putting dsp (being short for digital signal processing) in the URL, people who are new will assume it will only be for digital.

signals.stackexchange.com is the first thing that came to mind, but I by no means support it as a perfect URL.

---

**Update:** http://signals.stackexchange.com now redirects to the primary URL, http://dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Yep, this was my immediate thought. SigProc maybe. Signals.SE maybe.

Comment: I agree. I say signals.se is better

Comment: Ha, I edited my answer before I saw your guys comments, I added signals.se as an option as well.

Comment: `dsp` is OK, but I ♥ `signals`.

Comment: I think with 'signals' you can cover more ground (i.e. signal statistics, encoding of random processes) -- and that is the problem as then we get overlapping fields with stats.se. -- anyway is like signals more!

Comment: +1 for signals.se

Comment: Update: signals.stackexchange.com is now a working redirect. Sorry it took so long to implement, but now you can share that URL with your analog signal processing friends and they will feel welcome here!

Answer (score 1):

What about [sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28signal_processing%29)?

Granted, it's only an aspect of signal processing, but it's about finding a term that those in the field will readily (if not immediately) identify with.

Just as the statistics site is called "Cross Validated"; cross-validation (as opposed to say true validation or holdout validation) is only one way to perform validation of statistics.

Comment: Isn't sampling just one component of signal and image processing?

Comment: @GraceNote Yes, update answer to reflect that and why I feel it would still be appropriate.