# What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

Tags: discussion

We need this to be able to help market this site quickly to other people, so what can we come up with as a *good* elevator pitch for this site?

It'll help with things like the [name and URL](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/first-up-what-to-call-this-site) of the site as well ;)

Comment: Here is a blog post to learn more about the elevator pitch: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/

Answer (score 4):

Surely in need of some work, but here's a crack at it.

Elevator pitch:

Signals.SE is a free, community driven, question and answer site focused on topics relevant to analog and digital signal processing.  Our inclusive definition of a signal, a measurable physical quantity which can convey information, is designed to reach out to the widest audience.  Questions about underlying signal theory, filter design and algorithmic or mathematical techniques are welcome here while questions that are overly focused on implementation details or are overly mathematically natured are better answered elsewhere on the [Stack Exchange network of Q&A websites](http://stackexchange.com/sites).  Signals.SE was created through the open democratic process defined at [Stack Exchange Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I was trying to incorporate some of the issues I found on the Area 51 discussion page to give a bit of better focus but the on/off topic bit might be better served elsewhere in the faq

Comment: Do we need all the reference to Stack Exchange, and the "free, community driven," blurb?  This sounds overly glowing.  Also, typo: "Signals.SE is **a** free"

Comment: Oh, and this might start an edit war, but "analogue" ought to be spelled "analog" :)

Comment: I won't start a Canadian English vs American English debate on this one, and defer to the common use.

Comment: @KevinVermeer The "is a free ..." seems to be fairly common from one site to the next ... similar to the reference to Stack Exchange

Answer (score 2):

Tagline:

- Signals.SE - Bringing signal processing into focus.

Comment: Probably. Also helpful to review: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevator_pitch because an Elevator Pitch is more than a tag line.

Comment: @Stephen - Yes, they should be one per answer IMO.

Comment: "From time to frequency from frequency to time" - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkJpbfGp0hE

Comment: @rwong Funny, but painful to watch :-)

Answer (score 1):

Tagline:

- Signals.SE - Get the picture?

Answer (score 0):

Daily useful transformations one signal at a time.

---

I'm also trying to make a tagline combining both "finite impulse response" and "well-tempered". (alternatively, "stable" (laplace), "casual" (time-domain))

---

something that involves convolution?

Comment: Dont only focus on the tagline but also a short paragraph about the purpose of the site.

Comment: I think you're confusing the word [ca - **su** - al](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/casual) ( relaxed or unconcerned) with [c - **aus** - al](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_system) (a signal that's only dependent on past or present inputs, i.e. impulse response of zero for t < 0) - Not a mistake you want to make in the tagline!

Comment: Thanks @Kevin. In other words, because the tagline is going to be highly public and visible, puns / inside jokes are best avoided if it is likely to confuse the majority of (non-target) people.